# Show $1+x+(x^2/2!)+ \cdots + (x^n/n!)=0$ has no rational solutions for all $n>1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Prove that the equation $$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+ \cdots + \frac{x^n}{n!}=0$$ has no rational solutions for all $n>1$.

Assume there is a rational solution $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $(p,q)=1$, then by clearing denominator we have $p\mid n!$ and $q= \pm 1$. Hence the solution must be an integer solution. Furthermore, by considering it modulo $2$, $p$ must be even. But then I cannot proceed anymore.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, you know the solution has to be a negative integer. I'm not sure if that is of any use though.

Comment: I think for even $n$ it does not have any real solution.

Comment: ^Yeah, it seems that for odd $n$, $p_n(x)$ is strictly increasing with exactly one real root, and for even $n$, $p_n(x)$ is positive. (Here, $p_n(x) = 1+x+\cdots+x^n/n!$).

Comment: And the real root for odd $n$ moves toward $-\infty$, as this approximates $e^x$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: How does the solution that you accepted help you. It stopped there where you already were ($q=\pm 1, p \mid n!$)?

Comment: you should withdraw the acceptance of this answer. It does not make sense to accept an unvalid answer: The question is now a question with an accepted answer and so nobody who looks for open questions to answer will find it.

Answer (score 1):

For $|q|\ne 1$ Zubin's argument is fine. Otherwise, I have got an idea which I am presenting below. Please point out if something seems wrong.

For $|q|=1$, the solution $x$ is a negative integer , then you can show that the equation yields $$n!\left(1+x^2/2!+\cdots+x^{2k}/(2k)!\right)=n!\left(x+x^3/3!+\cdots+x^{2k+1}/(2k+1)!\right)$$ where $k=[n/2]$. Then $x|n!\Rightarrow n!=ax$ for some positive integer $a$. Then, we can see that this yields $a|x\Rightarrow x=ab$ which yields $n!=a^2b$ and in a similar manner we can see that this will result in $b|a$. So basically we can generate in this way a sequence $a_1,a_2,\cdots$ such that $a_1|x,a_2|a_1,\cdots$ and $n!=a_1x=a_1^2a_2=a_2^3a_3$ This will continue until we get some $m>1$ such that $a_m=1$ and then we will get $n!=a_{m-1}^m$. I **think** this is not possible which will lead us to a contradiction. I am trying to prove this last statement.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, for contradiction, that there exist $p,q,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n>1$ and $q>0$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $$1+\frac{p}{q}+\frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2+\frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^3+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^n =0$$

Multiplying by $n! \cdot q^n$, we get

$$q^nn!+pq^{n-1}n!+\frac{n!}{2!}p^2q^{n-2} + \cdots + \frac{n!}{n!}p^n=0$$

If we take the equation modulo $q$ we get $$p^n \equiv 0 \pmod{q}$$

This means $q \mid p^n$, but this is impossible since $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

---

**Edit**: The above answer is not correct. It only shows that $q=1$ and $p<0$.

Comment: what will happen if $q = 1$? am I missing something?

Comment: @Krish Wow, he fooled almost everyone. It really says that just $q\not>1$ which was already known ._.

Comment: @user2345215 "fooled" makes it seem intentional. I fooled myself as well :P

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I didn't mean it was intentional :) One fools themselves the most easily.